# converting UTC date string to local date string inspecific format

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have a UTC date in string

```
String utcDate = "2014-03-05 07:09:07.0";
```

I want to convert it to local date string of format `DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm a`
eg: `5-Mar-2014 12:39 PM` from UTC date `2014-03-05 07:09:07.0`

How this can be achieved using simple java or joda API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy to achieve with default functionality. I hope the local data is for display only.

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date parsed = parser.parse(utcDate);

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a");
System.out.println(formatter.format(parsed));
```

Answer (score 2):

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Instead use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in bundled with [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8).

If you use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format of strings, you can pass the string directly to a Joda-Time [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) constructor. Your input string is close, but the space in the middle should be a `T`.

Some example code using the Joda-Time 2.3 library.

```
String input = "2014-03-05 07:09:07.0";
String inputModified = input.replace( " ", "T" );

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( inputModified, DateTimeZone.UTC );

DateTime dateTimeParis = dateTimeUTC.toZone( timeZone );
String outputFrance = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "FF" ).withLocale(Locale.FRANCE).print( dateTimeParis );

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "d-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a" ).withLocale( Locale.US );
String outputParisCustom = formatter.print( dateTimeParis );
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will help you to convert your UTC to IST or any other timezone. You need to pay attention to the timezone that you want to use with SimpleDateFormat.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class ConvertTimeZone {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date = sdf.parse("2014-03-05 07:09:07");
        System.out.println("time in UTC " +sdf.format(date));
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
        System.out.println("Time in IST is " + sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```